# Need assistance with the format of a SQL Server table-valued function

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I have never used a TVF before and I need to use it to run a query in PowerBI DirectQuery.

I'm re-utilizing the query I already have in use in a stored procedure, where I declare and use a couple of variables to capture a date range.

I get the following error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usf_PBI_AgentProd, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 8]
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'

My code is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[usf_PBI_AgentProd]()    
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN

        SET DATEFIRST 7

        DECLARE @Oggi date = GETDATE() 
        DECLARE @Start datetime = CAST(@Oggi AS datetime) + CAST('00:00' AS datetime)
        DECLARE @End datetime = CAST(@Oggi AS datetime) + CAST('23:59' AS datetime);

        SELECT
            t.AgentName, t.AgtID, 
            n.SalesArea, t.TotRes, t.ResDate
        FROM
            rxtdoc t  
        INNER JOIN 
            rstdhdr n ON (1 = 1) 
        WHERE
            ResDate BETWEEN @Start AND @End
```

I know this might be entry level sql code for most of you, but at this moment I'm stuck, so I'd appreciate if any of you could lend a hand.
Thank you!!

Comment: I have to add that part of my code got cut off, on top I use the create function statement:
```CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[usf_PBI_AgentProd]()    ```

Answer (score 0):

Slight syntax error causing the issue.

You can only use

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.myFunct(x int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
```

if all you have in your function is a SELECT statement. You, however, have quite a few things *before* your SELECT statement that make this an issue.

If you have other things you want to do before you return data, use this syntax instead:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[usf_PBI_AgentProd2]()
  /** Note how you have to explicitly lay out your table definition **/
RETURNS @myReturnTable TABLE (  
    agentName   varchar(50),
    agtID       int,
    salesArea   varchar(150),
    totRes      int,
    resDate     datetime
)
AS
BEGIN;

    /* This seems really unnecessary, but you know your code best */
    SET DATEFIRST 7;
    DECLARE @Oggi           date    = getdate () ;
    DECLARE @Start      datetime    = CAST(@Oggi AS datetime) + CAST('00:00' AS datetime);
    DECLARE @End        datetime    = CAST(@Oggi AS datetime) + CAST('23:59' AS datetime);

    /* you can honestly do almost anything in this area */ 

    -- When you're ready to populate that return table, do so like this
    INSERT INTO @myReturnTable
    Select
        t.AgentName
        ,t.AgtID
        ,n.SalesArea
        ,t.TotRes
        ,t.ResDate

    from 
    rxtdoc t  
    INNER JOIN rstdhdr n ON(1=1) 

    where
        ResDate between @Start and @End

    RETURN;
END;
```

Some useful help: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-user-defined-functions/sql-server-table-valued-functions/

Comment: Happy to hear! Please remember to upvote and accept an answer if it helped.

Comment: I did upvote, but the system does not allow me to register it, as I don't have the 15 points of reputation yet. However it does say that it takes it into account, although I don't know how or even if that is computed. I am very greatful for your help!